# CakePHP3.3.15: FormHelper doesn't generate the right checkbox code

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm fighting with checkbox where CakePHP doesn't generate the right code and I can't understand why:

I initialize entities like that in my controller:

```
public $defaultPermissionFields = [
    /*
     * Module, item, item_visible, item_editable
     */
    ['item_visible' => 0],
    ['item_visible' => 1],
];

$permissions = $this->Permissions->newEntities($defaultPermissionFields);
```

So I have the following code in the ctp file:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($permissions, ['horizontal' => true])?>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="table-responsive well">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <?php foreach ($permissions as $key => $permission):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <?= $this->Form->checkbox('permissions.' . $key . '.item_visible', ['label' => false, 'value' => $permission->item_visible, 'required' => false]);?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__("Save"), ["class" => "btn btn-primary btn-block"]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

And strangely, the following code is generated:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="permissions[0][item_visible]" value="0"/>   <-- WHY ???
            <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[0][item_visible]" value="0">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="permissions[1][item_visible]" value="0"/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[1][item_visible]" value="1" checked="checked">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, for the second row, the checkbox value is `1` and it's checked and it's hidden value is `0`. That's the expected code.
**But**
For the first row, the checkbox value is `0` **AND** the hidden value is also `0` instead of 1.

Can you tell me why?

The second problem I have, but maybe caused by the first one is that I need to add `required => false` because whithout it, if I uncheck a checkbox, the browser tells me that I need to check the box !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up things. Why would you expect the hidden value to be anything other than `0`? Your checkbox obviously represents a boolean value, so by default the fallback value should be `0`, which represents the "not selected" state.

The actual problem is that the checkbox value should be `1` instead of `0`. It is `0` because you're using the wrong option, `value` is not ment to be used to determine the checked state, but to actually set the `value` attribute value. What you want to use is either the `checked`, or the `default` option, if any at all, given that the form helper should be able to read the value from the entities on its own.

Quote from the docs:

> - `checked` - boolean indicate that this checkbox is checked.
>
> [...]
>
> - `default` - Set the default value for the checkbox. This allows you to start checkboxes as checked, without having to check the POST data. A matching POST data value, will overwrite the default value.

Given that you probably want to keep user selections until the entity is actually being saved, you'd use the `default` option - if at all.

Also note that when passing the name of the base table to your inputs (that isn't actually required), make sure to use proper camel cased notation (ie. `Permissions` instead of `permissions`), as this does not represent an entity property!

Comment: You are right, the problem is not where I though. In fact I used `value` because the checkbox state don't reflect `item_` value. And here is my main problem. whatever the value of `item_visible`, the checkbox is checked and I don't understand why. It seems the problem comes from using items array and I don't think I use a bad notation.... Maybe you could have a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2ndGAB/a77a6b01822d82da27043c7b148a5847)